# iOS SIGABRT error on Build & Run

Tags: ios, objective-c

When I try to build any project, occasionally I'll get a SIGABRT from this method in `main.m`:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

It doesn't matter if i've modified the project or if I'm building a template that was just created, I'll occasionally get this error. If I close the debugger where the exception was raised and Build & Run again, the error goes away and the app runs fine.

This happens with any and all projects, ones that I have modified and ones that I have created from a template that were not modified. It always throws the first time I build it and every time I make a change to the code after that.

The only output displayed is "`(lldb)`".

Using XCode 4.6.2 on Mac OSX 10.8.4.

Comment: occasionally ? does it run without crashing ?

Comment: Unfortunately that's not enough information to be able to diagnose your problem. Have you found any situations in which you always (or at least often) get this crash? Details on that situation might be able to narrow down what the problem could be.

Comment: maybe you r forgetting to link something, or you are not including some library, but you need to tell us what are u doing to find where is wrong.

Comment: go to the breakpoint-navigator in xcode (cmd+6) and add a breakpoint for all exceptions, this will help (in most cases) to narrow the cause  of the error down.

Comment: The app runs without crashing. If I exit the debugger mode and Build & Run again, it will run fine. This usually occurs after I have made a few changes to the code, or even just browsed through it. I don't believe that I'm forgetting a library or a link, this occurs with projects that are from templates, even ones that I have not modified.

Comment: I typically see this error when I have something that isn't linked correctly.

Comment: @KeithSmiley as I said, it doesn't seem to be a linker error as I can create a new project without modifying the linker properties and this error will still be thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's a problem with permissions. I had the same problem time ago, and I discovered that it was happening if you create a project in a certain directory, and then you displace it in another directory and you try to run it from there.

Maybe there is a smarter solution, but I can tell you that if you delete the project and create a new one, copying all the files from the old project to the new one, without displacing it in another directory, it will not crash.

Comment: I'm creating all my projects on the Desktop, you're saying copy all the files i've modified and place them in a new project?

Comment: You're also running them from the desktop right? you haven't displaced them?

Comment: I created the projects on the desktop and have not modified the folders in any way.